# "Nothing but" + adjective?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Can "nothing but" be used before an adjective? E.g.:

```
I'm nothing but certain we will win.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this type of phrasing is not in use. You may be thinking of "all but certain". For example, "I'm all but certain we will win" is a fine phrase.

It's hard to prove this because of phrases like "Nothing but certain reactions...", but this [n-gram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+but+certain%2Call+but+certain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnothing%20but%20certain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20but%20certain%3B%2Cc0) provides evidence.

Comment: "all but" = almost, as in i'm *all but* certain this is not what the OP is intending to convey, but rather looking to reinforce the following adjective, not express doubt in it.

Comment: I was aware of the phrase "all but" + adjective, I was just wondering if "nothing but" could also be used (in any meaning) as well. So the answer's "no".

Answer (score 2):

*[Nothing but](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nothing-but?q=nothing%20but)* is an idiomatic phrase that means "*only*" in the sense of "solitary":

> Only:
>
> ***Nothing but*** the best will do.

The three words expressed in that phrase: *No thing but* yield the meaning [*Only*:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/only)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> [ATTRIBUTIVE]
>
> 1 Alone of its or their kind; single or solitary:
>
> ***Only*** boys sing in the boys choir.

If you substituted only in your sentence, you get an awkward arrangement:

> I'm ?only? certain we will win.

A person would have to pause and think about that expression to gather its meaning, and *nothing but* would tend to be even more confusing. As others have suggested *entirely* or another synonym of entirely (*completely, altogether, fully, perfectly, thoroughly, etc.*) would work much better.

Examining the data behind the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing%20but&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnothing%20but%3B%2Cc0), confirms that *nothing but* is almost always followed by a noun, and often a noun preceded by a determiner as in:

> - nothing but skin and bones
> - nothing but net
> - nothing but the truth
> - nothing but a liar

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: The example chosen is not a good one, and _nothing but_ nearly always modifies a noun phrase, not an adjective… and yet, I don't really think something like “I'm nothing but pleased for you!” is really unacceptable. Unusual, yes, but perfectly understandable and somehow not entirely wrong-sounding. And there's nothing logical or systematic that would preclude it: _anything but_ can modify both noun phrases and adjectives just fine.

Comment: It seems that predicate adjectives are a common exception to "the rule", and I would love to explore the cause of that exception. The "solely" definition of *only* invites an adverbial revolution with nothing but, which still seems to be content with a predominantly adjectival role.

Comment: Mine deleted too!

Answer (score 0):

As another respondent has pointed out, your example does not really work.

***Nothing but*** is usually used in the sense of: 'The person in the dock is ***nothing but a rogue and a scoundrel***'.

Answer (score -1):

The awkwardness of "nothing but" preceding an adjective has already been addressed in [other](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/230599/106801) [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/230608/106801).

If you are trying to reinforce the following adjective, you might try ***wholly***, ***completely***, or ***entirely***.

> I'm *entirely* certain we will win.

Comment: This is true, but does not answer the question at all. Also, your suggestion to drop the 'that' carefully included by Jeremy in his Ngram searches to cut down on noise was was counter-productive.

Comment: it's more useful to say that google ngrams shows zero hits for the latter phrase.  comparing to a null set is the same as not comparing at all.  even more so when the added word is entirely optional in english in the first place.